# Which of the following form an ideal in this ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $C(R)$ denote the ring of all continuous real-valued functions on
with the operations of pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication.
Which of the following form an ideal in this ring?

- The set of all $C^{\infty}$  functions with compact support.
- The set of all continuous functions with compact support.
- The set of all continuous functions which vanish at infinity, i.e. functions
  such that 
  $$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x) = 0$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: "Set of all $C^\infty$" is a little weird to say, but I guess you mean the subset of [smooth functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitely_differentiable_function) $C^\infty\subset C(R)$?

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of a subring, an ideal of $C(\mathbb{R})$ would be a subset $I$ of $C(\mathbb{R})$ such that:

- For $f_1,f_2 \in I$, $f_1 + f_2 \in I$
- For any $f \in I$ and any $g \in C(\mathbb{R})$, $f\cdot g \in I$.

With that in mind, the set of continuous functions with compact support is the only set you've described satisfying all of these properties.

### Why the other sets fail to be ideals:

#### The set $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$:

Note that $f = 1$ given by $f(x) = 1$ is in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $g$ given by $g(x) = |x|\in C(\mathbb{R})$, but $f\cdot g = g \not \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Incidentally, this is why no proper subset of a ring containing the multiplicative identity can be an ideal of that ring.

#### The set of functions with compact support:

Not all such functions are continuous, and so this fails to be a subset of $C(\mathbb{R})$ (I'll leave it to you to find a counterexample).  Thus, it is not an ideal thereof.

#### The set $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ of continuous functions vanishing at $\pm \infty$

Note that $f$ given by $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ is in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$, and $g$ given by $g(x) = e^{|x|}$ is continuous.  However, $f \cdot g = 1$ is not in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: It would be quite useful to see why the others dont satisfy this definition

Comment: how The set of all continuous functions with compact support becomes an ideal u did not explain......................

Comment: It seems that the question has changed since I posted my answer, so the first two non-ideals no longer apply.

Comment: @sani you're right, and I don't intend to.  If you have a question about it, perhaps you should post a new question.

Comment: so what will be the answer? How u prove ?

Comment: [perhaps you should post a new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)